# Testing Response.SetCookie() with MvcContrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

In my Controller Action I set Cookie with Response.SetCookie(myCookie) method.
In my Unit Test method I would like to use Mock or better Stub to examine if all parameters have been set correctly. I am using MvcContrib TestHelper to setup HttpContext but I don't know how to pass my fake Response object to it. I am using Moq and MvcContrib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock HttpContext property on TestControllerBuilder yourself. HttContext is marked protected so your test class needs to inherit from TestControllerBuilder to be able to set it. I did it like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class SampleTest : TestControllerBuilder
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLogOnActionSetsCookie()
    {
        var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        httpContextMock.Setup(c => c.Response)
            .Returns(responseMock.Object);

        responseMock
                .Setup(r => r.SetCookie(It.IsAny<HttpCookie>()))
                .Verifiable();

        var controller = new AccountController();

        base.HttpContext = httpContextMock.Object;
        base.InitializeController(controller);

        controller.LogOn();

        responseMock.Verify();
    }
}
```